# Logging into facebook with java

Tags: java, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to log into facebook, I'm new to this so I hope you can give me some pointers.

I'm trying spring social, because is the only one I found with a [complete example](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-quickstart), which logs in successfully, but it doesn't delete the cookie once I log out(even when I tried to set the cookie max age to 0).

So please can anyone tell me how to fix this or maybe a better(or easier) way to do this [log in]?

I thank your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that setting the max age to 0 will work in this case.  Try to use method removeCookie from the class UserCookieGenerator instead - https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples/commit/431be39b3132ed8f5e2ebe377515f7da20c8ef17#diff-5

Hope it helps